# .Net Core passing connection string to DBContext class

Tags: asp.net-core

Just started using .Net Core and facing passing connection string information to Context console project.

I have 4 projects, created using .Net Core.

1. MVC
2. Service Layer
3. Domain Layer
4. Data Layer

In MVC project, I have Startup.cs file where i am reading appsettings.json file

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

            services.AddMvc();

            // Add appsettings
            services.Configure<AppSettingsConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")); 
}


public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
            builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
        }
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

In my 4th project (Data Layer), which Console Project and having following DBContext class. This project doesn't have Startup.cs as i MVC project having. Not created by default by VS 2015.

```
public class MyDWContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDWContext() : base ()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {            
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDW; Persist Security Info = False; User ID = TempUser; Password = Temp123");
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Class> Classs { get; set; }
}
```

I have been to other post as well but i believe its created using older version or RC version. So some time i cannot find correct object or .Net classes.

As i have connection string is in MVC project, how can i use connection string during my MVC call to Data layer.

I have Web.API (Core) project as well and that having own connection string (different user configuration in connection string which having only read access). How can i use Web2.API connection string when i am making call from Web2.API project.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of passing connection string to `DbContext`, configuring `DbContext` in `Startup.cs`(if possible) is better way. See official [docs](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html#register-your-context-with-dependency-injection) to understand how to configure `DbContext` and use it via Dependency Injection.

**EDIT : Below code is not good way**

However, if you want to pass connection string to `DbContext` you can use [options pattern](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#using-options-and-configuration-objects).

Here is an example how to pass connection string with options pattern:

First you need an options class which accessible from Data Layer and MVC layer

```
public class ConnectionStringOption
{
     public string ConStr { get ; set; }
}
```

Then set option value

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddOptions();
     services.Configure<ConnectionStringOption>(options=>
     {
         // set connection string from configuration  
         options.ConStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");
     });      
}
```

`appsetting.json`

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "<your connection string>"
  }
}
```

Finally `DbContext`

```
    private readonly IOptions<ConnectionStringOption> _conStrOptions;

    protected YourDbContext()
    {
    }
    public YourDbContext(IOptions<ConnectionStringOption> conStrOptions, DbContextOptions options) 
        : base(options)
    {
        _conStrOptions= conStrOptions;
    }
```

**Edit for another way**

Using Static Service Locator may be a solution:

Create a `DependencyResolver` in Data Layer

```
public static class DependencyResolver
{
    private static IServiceProvider _provider;
    public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider
    {
        get
        {
            return _provider;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_provider == null)
            {
                _provider = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `ConfigureServices` method

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // other stuff
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<ConnectionStringOption>(options=>
        {
            // set connection string from configuration  
            options.ConStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");
        }); 
        DependencyResolver.ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
```

And finally get option:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{            
    var conStr = DependencyResolver.ServiceLocator.GetService<IOptions<ConnectionStringOption>>().Value.ConStr;
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer();
}
```

**Final Edit for previous stupid way**

```
public static class ConnectionStringGetter
{
    public static string ConStr{get;set;}
}

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //...
    Configuration = builder.Build();
    ConnectionStringGetter.ConStr =  Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{            
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionStringGetter.ConStr);
}
```

Comment: Don't mind second way, it seems it is not valid way.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But can i use _conStrOptions property into OnConfiguring function at Data Layer.    <code> protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {}</code>

Comment: Yes you can, but in this case you should use `OnConfiguring` to configure `DbContext` and your `DbContext` will depend on Database(such as SqlServer) provider. I think it is not good practice.

Comment: _ConStrOptions is null during following call.   optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_conStrOptions.Value.ConStr);

Comment: Did you configure `DbContext` in `Startup.cs` like : `services.AddDbContext<YourDbContextContext>();`?

Comment: **Edit for another way** option work for me. Great.. Thanks Again

Comment: Actually i later realized that last way is just using static variable. So using options and dependency resolver is not a matter. Just using static varible gets same result. I edited my answer.

Comment: I believe you have changed class name **ConnectionStringOption** to **ConnectionStringGetter** and make it static. In this  case Startup.cs in MVC project having following error. **annot convert lambda expression to type 'IConfiguration' because it is not a delegate type GCIC.Web..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0**

Comment: `code` services.Configure<ConnectionStringGetter>(options =>
            {
               options.ConStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection");
            });
            DependencyResolver.ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(); `code`

Comment: You don't need to configure `ConnectionStringGetter`, remove it.

Comment: So do you think any modification has been required into step **Final Edit for previous stupid way** for any improvement?

Comment: Sorry, in startup.cs you need to set static varible with connectionstring. I edited code.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Final solution is good to resolve issue without using **DI**

Comment: Works like a charm with ef core 2.1