# .NET core - read connection string into Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

My project structure is pretty standard:

[image: Project structure]

within `EFData`.

`EFData` is an Entity Framework Core class library that isolates all of the database interaction. Database models, and my `DBContext`. I built it that way so that it's database environment agnostic.

The API project of course has a reference to `EFData`.

How do I pass the connection string from `Startup.cs` in `API` to `DBContext.cs` in `EFData`?

I've read multiple articles that reference a set up different than mine where I might expect a `Startup.cs` in my `EFData` project. I don't have that.

Within `Startup.cs`, I do have what I thought was the required line -

```
services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

But `EFData` knows nothing about that connection string.

Comment: EFData doesn't need a startup file. If you place that AddDbContext call into your startup file within API, what value is coming back with that GetConnectionString call? Does your appsettings file have a connectionstring with that name?

Comment: The connection string returned is the one I'd expect based on my environment. Yes, the appsettings that corresponds to that environment has a connection with that name. @ShaneBauer

Comment: Without seeing how you intended to use the DBContext class, this is going to be hard to answer. How does your code use that context in the API project?

Comment: All of my database interaction is within that class library which I wanted to keep seperate from the API code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.Net Core passing connection string to DBContext class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090206/net-core-passing-connection-string-to-dbcontext-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach can be adding a ConnectionString property in the DBContext.cs class and then setting it on the startup.cs of the API project explicitly.
Add the following code in DBcontext.cs

```
   using System;
   using System.Data.SqlClient;

   using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

   public class DBContext 
   {
       public static void SetConnectionString(string connectionString)
       {
           if (ConnectionString == null)

           {
               ConnectionString = connectionString;
           }
           else
           {
               throw new Exception();
           }
       }
       // this part will help you to open the connection
       public static SqlConnection OpenConnection()
       {
           SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
           connection.Open();
           return connection;
       }

       private static string ConnectionString { get; set; }

       //add the connectionString to options

         protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
       {
           if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
           {
               optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
           }
       }
   }
```

Now, in the API project add a reference of the EFData project and in the startup.cs file set the ConnectionString

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var connectionString = this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBName");
            Namespace.DBContextContext.SetConnectionString(connectionString); //replace namespace with the namespace suitable for your solution

            //here goes rest of your default code
        }
```

This way you should be able to access the Connection in your API project.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to Get Connection and build your database

1. Add reference to EFData Project in API project - do this by in the
   API project, clicking on the dependecies section and adding
   reference to your EFData class library.
2. Then add to your startup class in your api project and ensure the connection string is in your ConfigureServices method or similar

your connection string looks good just make sure your database connection string is correct.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings#aspnet-core) is a link if you need more information

Comment: My EFData project does not have a startup.cs

Comment: Does your APi Project have one?

Comment: Yes, My API Project has a Startup.cs

Comment: So there are 3 things you need to do;

1. On your API project expand that section in Visual Studio (i assume from the screenshot) then right click on the item that says 'Dependencies', and then you will see the option to 'Add Reference', There you will see a list of projects in your solution and select EFData.

Now your API project which is initialised on startup can initialize the EFData class library when you run the project.

Comment: 2. Then you need to go into your startup class and in the ConfigureServices method add in the connection string you had and then you will need to reference the name space for your DBContext

3. Finall then you need to ensure the correct connection string is in your appsettings.json file by the name of 'DefaultConnection' so then it can be picked up on start up

You may need to run your migrations and so on to build your database, but that should get you to the place you need

Comment: This line - services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))); references the correct DBContext from my EFData class library. What do I need to do in the code within me DBContext file to pick up that connection string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198973/discussion-between-duckmike-and-callistus-asirvatham).

Comment: ASP.NET core uses dependency injection, so as you have configured the connection string and specified the context to inject the connection string into when you debug the project it will auto build it.

best way to test is in PM console run your migrations in the correct project, it will work,