# How do I pass connection string to DBContext in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, db-first

Is it possible to configure/pass connection string to the `DbContext` in the constructor?

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() { }
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) { }
}

MyContext opt = new MyContext("con_str");
```

rather than hard coding it in:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
        @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDB;Integrated Security=True");
}
```

How do I use:

```
DbContextOptions<MyContext> opts;
```

The following answer: [Pass connection string to code-first DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805094/pass-connection-string-to-code-first-dbcontext) does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.Net Core passing connection string to DBContext class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090206/net-core-passing-connection-string-to-dbcontext-class)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options =>
{
     options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetSection("YourConn").Value);
     options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
});
```

### appsettings.json

```
"YourConn": "yourconnectionstring"
```

### EDITED

### YourDbContext.cs

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    private string _conn = "";
    public MyContext(string conn) 
    { 
        _conn = conn;
    }
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) { }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
         optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_conn);
    }
}
```

Then you can use

```
MyContext opt = new MyContext("con_str");
```

Comment: What is startup.cs and appsettings.json. I don't use ASP.net core. I have remowed DI tag. What is services object?

Comment: what you use? winform?

Comment: Currently console application.

Comment: i edited post. you can check. Ignore startup.cs and appsettings.json.

Comment: Thx. That's what I needed.

Comment: Thank you @Asherguru, anyway I really had to implement this on bad condition that I really hate at... *look into my code, and cry...

Comment: DbContextOptions doesnt exist for me?